# Way to override builtin function and have it carry over to external python script call (ie os.system("Script2.py"))

Tags: python, environment, built-in

Is there any way to do this? I want to call Script2.py in Script1.py via os.system() or subprocess, but Script2.py contains raw_input builtins that I want to override with a custom raw_input function I wrote in Script1.py.

This can clearly be done If I import Script2.py and call its classes instead, but I would like to call it via os.system.

Comment: Can you provide small example of what you want do? So that the problem is easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Add this wrapper to end of script2.py

```
import sys 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

And then call it directly like:

```
func = os.popen('python.exe script2.py raw_input').read()
```

func is the result.